# How to add custom javascript in observer magento2

Tags: magento2, javascript

Im using sales_order_place_before event and want to execute some javascript when my observer executes.

```
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    //add something here
}
```

note:do not use object manager!

Comment: javascript is a client side language while observer is being run at server side. You cannot run a client side script in your server side observer.

Comment: thanks for the answer but it can be possible like this:
           $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
            $layout->getUpdate()->addUpdate('
            reference name="head">
                <block type="core/text" name="myjs">
                    <action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<script type="text/javascript">
                   //code goes here
            </script>]]></text></action>
                </block>
            </reference>');
            $layout->getUpdate()->load();
            $layout->generateXml();

Comment: Hello @nihal, do we have solution for this? Pls update as answer, Thanks